# How to make movable type to use relative path

Tags: movabletype

Commonly movable type will publish HTML files which contains absolute path, but if I want to host the site under different domain(e.g., both HTTP and HTTPS), it is very inconvenient.

So is there a way to change all the paths to resource of my site to absolute ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want "reletive" paths. The relative directories can be symlinked/aliased on the server. Once file paths are aliased...

Update your mt-config.cgi file to use reletive paths for the required [config directives](http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/config-directives/):

- [StaticWebPath](http://www.movabletype.org/config/StaticWebPath)
- [CGIPath](http://www.movabletype.org/config/CGIPath)

This is also covered in the [installation guide](http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/installation/)

Comment: Hi, It is strange that it dosen't work. I have changed the CGIPath and StaticWebPath to relative path and it still publish files containing absolute path

Answer (score 1):

Short of constructing the URLs yourself in your templates, you'll need a plugin.  I've found that [MTRelativeURL](http://www.nonplus.net/software/mt/MTRelativeURL.htm) works well, despite not being updated in a while.

The plugin adds a few new tags but the simple approach is to use the 'relative_url' filter where needed:

```
<$MTEntryPermalink relative_url="1"$>
```

Keep in mind that you'll want to continue using absolute URLs for the links in your RSS feed.